# What is the reason I have to include a url as my my simple_form argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My code did not work when I did

```
<%= simple_form_for @lesson do |f| %>
```

But worked when I did

```
<%= simple_form_for @lesson, url: course_lessons_path do |f| %>
```

My routes are

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action
    course_lessons GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#index
                   POST   /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#create
 new_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/new(.:format)      lessons#new
edit_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/edit(.:format) lessons#edit
     course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#show
                   PATCH  /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                   PUT    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                   DELETE /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#destroy
           courses GET    /courses(.:format)                             courses#index
                   POST   /courses(.:format)                             courses#create
        new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)                         courses#new
       edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                    courses#edit
            course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#show
                   PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                   PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                   DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#destroy
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the association as I was able to do

```
<%= simple_form_for @course do |f| %>
```

for the view for my courses.But I'm not entirely sure why I need a url and whether there are better. cleaner ways to edit my simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

rails has convention, since you using model name **lesson** but your controller that handle lesson is **course_lesson**, if you put

```
<%= simple_form_for @lesson do |f| %>
```

this will try to find lesson_controller, this is the reason you have to provide rails more information with url option

this also answer your question why

```
<%= simple_form_for @course do |f| %>
```

is working without url, since your model is course and your controller is also course_controller